# Validation for Tkinter Entry Runs Only Once

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am trying to implement a way of an entry only accepting integers being typed into it but I am struggling to get the code to work as desired. As I understand:

- The entry widget has a parameter `validate` which chooses when the validation should take place.
- The parameter `validatecommand` decides how the data should be restricted
- When validate is equal to 'key', at every keystroke, the string inside the entry is checked against the rules specified in `validatecommand`

However, after attempting this I got the issue that it only the validates the string in the entry at the before even clicking on it.

```
from tkinter import*
root = Tk()

def equationpage(root):
    vcmd = root.register(validate)
    A_str = IntVar()
    A_str.set(1)
    a = Entry(root,width="2",textvariable=A_str,validate = "key",validatecommand = (vcmd,'%p'))
    a.place(x=0,y=0)
def validate(inp):
    try:
        float(inp)
    except:
        return False
    return True
equationpage(root)
mainloop()
```

With the code above no validation takes place and it lets me type anything into the entry. If I change the code above so that there is no default value for the entry I end up not being able to type anything into the entry as it keeps rejecting the input.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4140988/7032856), there's no defined Tcl variable: `'%p'` for this option.

Replace:

```
'%p'
```

to include the *uppercase* ***P*** instead:

```
'%P'
```

Comment: Wow, thank you it now works. I can't believe it was an error that simple. I did just realise I didn't explicitly ask a question. My brain was fried after spending hours on the problem.